What's the difference between fatally, mortally, and gravely wounded?
I came over three words in a particular case where I feel that there's no real difference. Here's the three variants of the sentence:
He was fatally wounded.

He was gravely wounded.

He was mortally wounded.

Can anyone please explain what's the difference here? Because I feel all three convey the same meaning: he was wounded, and is about to die of his injuries.
Am I correct? Or, is there actually a difference between those three? Thanks in advance!

Note: I'm relatively new to this site, so please tell me if my posts are good enough or of use to the community and if not how to improve.

You needed to list the definitions you found first. Gravely wounded means he is not dead yet.

@YosefBaskin I agree, but doesn't the other two also mean he's not dead yet?

If not dead, he was not shot fatally. Only way to call it fatal is to die.

@YosefBaskin Perhaps there's some difference in order of these three words, i.e. gravely then fatally and then mortally, or something like that?

@YosefBaskin But I never said he was shot.

@YosefBaskin So, do you mean that fatal can only be used after death? Does it goes the same for mortally?

Fatally is dead. Mortally is dead. Finito la comedia. Geshtorben. Se acabo. If figuratively, it means very serious: a fatal flaw, but not necessarily a deal breaker. But that's the metophorical use.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There’s always a dictionary, when things get really tough.

Which dictionary do you recommend? I use Merriam Webster, but it doesn't have the "gravely" definition. So, can you please give me some suggestions?

In MW, it's listed under grave.

"Gravely" doesn't mean "related to the grave (place you put dead people)" - confusingly "grave" in the sense of "serious" is from Latin gravis, "heavy", while "grave" meaning "thing you dig" is from an unrelated Germanic root (c.f. German grab "tomb"). This may be in the dictionary, but you may not get the full etymology there.

@LukeL you can bookmark several dictionaries and consult more than one. Some are specialist, for example a technology dictionary, a dictionary of slang, etc.

Since this question is closed, please don't downvote, OK? There's no point in doing so. I already got the answer I want, and I suggest that whoever downvoted my answer should instead try to delete this question. I can't, since this is already answered.

Fatally wounded and mortally wounded means he died.
Gravely wounded means he was seriously wounded but may or may not have died.
("Fatally = mortally > gravely".)

Thanks for your answer! It is exactly what I'm looking for.

You should know, though, that the fatally and mortally wounded may not die immediately.

To me, fatally means that he has died, mortally could mean that he is still alive but will certainly die soon.
